# Объединение данных с json

Tags: javascript, json

Добрый день, помогите решить такую задачку есть такие данные:

```
  {
  "goods" : [ null, 1: {
    "cooking_time" : 90,
    "holding_time" : 120,
    "name" : "Ватрушка с творогом",
    "price" : 11
  }, 2: {
    "cooking_time" : 110,
    "holding_time" : 120,
    "name" : "Слойка с ветчиной",
    "price" : 8.22
  }, 3: {
    "cooking_time" : 3,
    "holding_time" : 3,
    "name" : "Латэ",
    "price" : 9.2
  }, {
    "cooking_time" : 2,
    "holding_time" : 3,
    "name" : "Американо",
    "price" : 5.5
  }, 4: {
    "cooking_time" : 120,
    "holding_time" : 120,
    "name" : "Круассан с шоколадом",
    "price" : 11.45
  }, null, {
    "cooking_time" : 100,
    "holding_time" : 120,
    "name" : "Хлеб Славянский",
    "price" : 8.22
  }, 5: {
    "cooking_time" : 80,
    "holding_time" : 120,
    "name" : "Пампушка",
    "price" : 14.2
  }, 6: {
    "cooking_time" : 130,
    "holding_time" : 120,
    "name" : "Бублик с маком",
    "price" : 12.5
  } ],
  "requested_orders" : {
    "32605d70-6d51-49cf-b814-2b8d56dc8361" : {
      "alias" : 1815,
      "items" : [ null, null, {
        "count" : 1
      }, {
        "count" : 3
      }, {
        "count" : 2
      }, null, null, {
        "count" : 1
      } ]
    },
    "5dbd403e-69e9-400f-b9bc-e54a173cf23a" : {
      "alias" : 7834,
      "items" : [ null, null, {
        "count" : 1
      }, {
        "count" : 3
      } ]
    },
    "5e7f25dc-8542-4d38-a261-64a7d8f0507b" : {
      "alias" : 3313,
      "items" : {
        "1" : {
          "count" : 2
        },
        "5" : {
          "count" : 1
        },
        "7" : {
          "count" : 3
        }
      }
    },
    "acef154-0331-4172-bfdf-fd5d0f727ddc" : {
      "alias" : 5512,
      "items" : {
        "2" : {
          "count" : 5
        },
        "7" : {
          "count" : 2
        }
      },
      "time" : 1511435700
    },
    "bc6c9bb7-0331-4172-bfdf-fd5d0f727ddc" : {
      "alias" : 2290,
      "items" : [ null, null, {
        "count" : 1
      }, {
        "count" : 1
      }, {
        "count" : 2
      }, {
        "count" : 10
      }, null, {
        "count" : 1
      } ]
    },
    "c18abbf5-3b38-458b-a6e9-2802097d72cb" : {
      "alias" : 1910,
      "items" : {
        "7" : {
          "count" : 2
        },
        "8" : {
          "count" : 1
        },
        "9" : {
          "count" : 3
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Нужно сделать проверку в `requested_orders -> items` по `key` и если где-то в `requested_orders -> items` ключи совпадают, суммировать ихние `count`. После найти в goods совпадение по ключам и к ним добавить этот `count` которые получили в `requested_orders`.

Просто вывести данные получается:

```
{Object.keys(this.props.requestedOrders).map((key, index) => {
    let data = this.props.requestedOrders[key];
    return (
        <div key={index}>
            {Object.keys(data.items).map((item) => {
                let items = data.items[item];
                let goods = this.props.goods[item];
                if(goods && items !== null) {
                    return (
                        <div key={item} className="group-element">
                            <div className="group-title">
                                <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
                                <span className="group-name">{goods.name}</span>
                            </div>
                            <p className="group-count">{items.count}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            })}
        </div>
    );
})}
```

Получается такой list:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И какие проблемы в вашем коде возникли?

Comment: Не знаю каким методом сделать первую проверку что-бы суммировать `count` :(